# JackRabbit - Removal of duplicate rows

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I have asked this question on jackrabbit-users list but I didn't get an answer.

*JCR-SQL2 doesn't provide a SELECT DISTINCT (or similar, AFAIK). Neither do SQL or XPATH in JCR 1.0... How are people getting around this?.  What's the best way of removing duplicate rows?*

*I read that someone was iterating over the results and putting them in a Set. In my case, because of the possible huge number of results, that approach may end up being too costly.*

Does anyone here have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

None of the query languages defined in JCR 1.0 (e.g., JSR-170) or JCR 2.0 (e.g., JSR-283) have a notion of `SELECT DISTINCT`.

The only way to do this is to process the results manually and throwing out any rows (or nodes) that you've already seen. Using a set of paths or Node objects would work. This isn't too difficult, but it's unfortunately harder than it should be and, as you mention, can be expensive if there are a lot of rows and/or duplicates.

This is why [ModeShape](http://modeshape.org) provides full support for JCR-SQL2 queries but also allows use of `SELECT DISTINCT`. In fact, ModeShape supports a number of other features such as

- non-correlated subqueries in the `WHERE` clause
- `LIMIT n` and `OFFSET m`
- `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`
- `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN`
- `BETWEEN` criteria
- set criteria, using `IN` and `NOT IN`
- `DEPTH` and `PATH` dynamic operands

and a few others. For details, see the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/modeshape/latest/manuals/reference/html_single/reference-guide-en.html#jcr-sql2-query-language).

Comment: Thanks Randall, I knew that Modeshape had implemented DISTINCT and  I was actually thinking on asking a few things about Modeshape later.  I'm considering migrating to Modeshape a possibility but there's one feature in JackRabbit I'm using that I don't know if Modeshape has, http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExcerptProvider

Comment: Miguel. You are right - ModeShape doesn't have that feature yet. Ask for it on our forums!